# handle multiple table in servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets, persistence

I am doing retrieve for memberinfo. At first, I get memberID and pass into a servlet
the following code is in the servlet's process request method

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String memId = request.getParameter("memId");
Member memInfo = (Member)em.createNamedQuery("Member.findByMemberId").setParameter("memberId", memId).getSingleResult();

 session.setAttribute("memInfo", memInfo);
 response.sendRedirect("Retrieve.jsp");
```

This is the constructor for each classes.

```
School schh = new School(sch);
Programme progr = new Programme(pro, schh);
Student stu = new Student(stuID, name, progr, gender, ic, hp, yos);
Member mem = new Member(memID, stu, regDate, memSta);
```

whenever I go out from servlet, i get this error.
owing to too long paragraph, i choose to post the link here http://goo.gl/4dwfeo

Answer (score 0):

Ok I respond in the other post the solution. The problem is the mapping of the Column in the Student. JPA use the default values to tries to map the table.